# How can I invoke my code in bash like most compilers/interpreters are invoked? i.e. when someone types "python <file>", "java <file>" or "g++ <file>"

Tags: bash, macos, command-line, scripting

I am on Mac, but it would be best if there was a way to do this on any platform.

I want my program to behave as if it is an "HTML Compiler" - namely, to behave like the compilers/interpreters for Python, Java, C, C++, Node, etc. I don't understand how to install the program in bash so that I can invoke it like those other ones are invoked.

Namely, I want to run my program with

1. a global command (meaning accessible from any directory),
2. an optional specified argument for the HTML file, and also
3. context of which directory the command came from (so that the program can make later changes to that directory).

This is what it should look like:
`parchment index.html` or `parchment .`

I know how to make aliases and custom scripts in bash, but there is some piece missing where I can't figure out how to get all of these functionalities.

If it matters, the program itself is written in Java, and currently not an executable. I run it in the directory it is in by typing "java Parchment".

Thanks!

Comment: Add a valid ```#!/usr/bin/python``` (or wherever your python binary is) to the python script,  ```chmod 755 <python file>``` (or whatever executable permission) .

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your question is. All the functionality you are asking for is builtin to the way most OSes start new processes. As long as the script is located on the `PATH` it will be globally available for the user and will always know the current working directory (the directory the command was called from)

Comment: Ok, maybe I wasn't clear - my program is not a python program, it is serving the role that python itself (the interpreter/compiler) would be. It is a program to run html files, written in Java. I'm asking how I can get the same functionality as pretty much all interpreters / compilers have - the global command, ability to accept arguments, and context local to where it is run.

Comment: What is a _global command_ and what do you mean by _context_? In Java, the main function **does** accept arguments. Since it is absolutely unclear (to me at least) what you are asking here, I suggest that you describe the proposed behaviour, the programming language you are going to use (you tag it as Java, mention Python, and say in your comment that it's in Java!), and the code which you already have to fulfill your needs, so that we can see at which point you got stuck. Please focus on a **single** problem in each quesion here.

Comment: I'm not sure what to say except that the language doesn't matter. I want my program to behave as if it is an "HTML Compiler" - namely, to behave like the compilers/interpreters for Python, Java, C, C++, Node, etc. I simply don't understand how to install the program in bash so that I can invoke it like those other ones.

Comment: @metacryst if you follow the steps I included in my answer you will

Comment: sed -i '' -E 's/assertEquals\("([^"]*)",\s*([^,)]*)(,\s*([^,)]*))?\)/assertEquals(\2\3, "\1")/g' file.java

Answer (score 0):

Create `parchment` like this

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import os
import sys

print('arg:', sys.argv)
print('cwd:', os.getcwd())
```

then

```
chmod +x parchment
```

You can run it from anywhere on your filesystem, like

```
/path/to/your/parchment
```

If you don't want to specify the absolute (or relative) path, `parchment` should be in a directory in your `PATH`. Check

```
echo $PATH
```

and move it to a directory in there

```
mv parchment /Users/myuser/bin/
```

#### edit

One more clarification. Once you have done all of these steps do:

```
parchment myfile.html
```

and see the output.